# How to access a non-public variable in a base class?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

I'm in a method of a derived class, loosely as follows:

```
Class Base
{
   private:
     int variableIWantToAccess;

}

Class Derived : public Base
{

   public someMethod() {
        variableIWantToAccess++;   <<-----ERROR

}
```

How do I access the variable that's declared in the base class? I'm unable to access it because it is private.

Comment: You cannot, make your field a protected property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the field private and create a pair of protected *getter* / *setter* methods instead (for the same reasons you wouldn't expose a public field).

```
Class Base
{
   private:
     int variableIWantToAccess;

   protected:
     int GetVariable() { return variableIWantToAccess; }
     void SetVariable(int var) { variableIWantToAccess = var; }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should declare it as `protected` instead of `private`.
`Protected` members of a class are accessible for the class descendants only.

Comment: Apparently a protected function that acts as a getter is the way to go, not declare the variable as protected, but you definitely pointed me in the exact right direction, thank you